# How to create select list with field_create_field($field) drupal 7 with options

Tags: drupal-7, field, entities

How to create select list, radio buttons, checkboxes with field_create_field() and how to specify the options to be given in these fields

Answer (score 1):

Run this code with the details for an existing field with the properties that you want to copy:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$field_name = 'body';
$bundle_name = 'article';

$info_config = field_info_field($field_name);
$info_instance = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name);
unset($info_config['id']);
unset($info_instance['id'], $info_instance['field_id']);
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/utility.inc';
$output = "field_create_field(" . drupal_var_export($info_config) . ");\n";
$output .= "field_create_instance(" . drupal_var_export($info_instance) . ");";
drupal_set_message("<textarea rows=30 style=\"width: 100%;\">". $output .'</textarea>');
```

That will produce the PHP code used to create the field/field instance. Then you just need to go through the code and make the changes for your new field/instance.